# limit number of token in one address ethereum

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, erc-223

Is it possible to create a token that each ethereum address can not exceed 100,000 token.

If the token amount exceed the 100,000, it will "overflow" and retrieve the transaction.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like:

```
mapping(address => uint) balance;

function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balance[msg.sender] >= tokens);    
    require(balance[to] + tokens <= 100000);
    balance[msg.sender] = balance[msg.sender]-tokens;
    balance[to] = balance[to]+tokens;
    return true;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

When a transfer occurs, you simply have to check that the receiver's balance doesn't exceed the amount you fixed.